# Cannot open asp.net mvc website in browser using IIS express

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

I cannot open asp.net mvc website(c#) with the url "https://localhost:44366" in browser when the mode is "IIS Express". But when I use the mode "WebApplication5", I can open https://localhost:5001.

launchSettings.json

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44179",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication5": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 Output when debugging:

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:44179/" for site "WebApplication5" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44366/" for site "WebApplication5" application "/"
Registration completed for site "WebApplication5"
IIS Express is running.
```

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\zhangsiyu\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\bin\Debug\net5.0\WebApplication5.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\netstandard.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Comment: add `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",` in `IIS EXPRESS` section

Comment: @viveknuna I have tried but not working.

Comment: have you tried `"launchUrl": "default"`. where `default` is your default controller name

Comment: @viveknuna I created a new project and unchecked the "Configure for HTTPS" option. And it's working now.Thanks anyway.:)

Comment: another way you can just set `"sslPort": 0`, it will work. no need to create new project

Comment: @viveknuna good stuff.

Comment: shall I post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"sslPort": 0` in the appsettings.json file. it will work as HTTP.